# Change "email" to "user_email" in users table for Auth::login

Tags: laravel, authentication

Porting a project from Laravel 3 :/ to Laravel 5.4

Come across an issue where I can't login, Due to the column being named "**user_email**" not "**email**"

Is there a way I can tell the login trait to recognise the user_email column to action the login?

Cheers

Comment: Try this : http://laraveldaily.com/auth-login-with-username-instead-of-email/

Comment: use user_emil in Auth::attempt

Answer (score 0):

You may define a username method on your LoginController:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'user_email';
}
```

Comment: Hi, AuthController is not used in Laravel 5.4. It looks like its split out

Comment: You are right! I edited the answer. Please try with this code.

Comment: A better way is

    public function getUsernameAttribute()
    {
        return "user_email";
    }